# How to capture an image with the webcam and send it through the octet stream to microsoft's face api

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to capture an image with the webcam of the device and send it through microsoft's face API to derive the person's emotion, etc.
I am recording and capturing the photo and convert it into the jpeg format and then in binary which the API demands. but when I send the request it gives me an error.

```
captureButton.addEventListener('click', () => {   
context.drawImage(player, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
x=context.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
x=convertCanvasToImage(canvas);
y=tobinary(x);

});






function processImage(stream) {

var subscriptionKey = "{MY_SUBSCRIPTION_KEY}";

var uriBase =
    "https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect";
var params = {
    "returnFaceId": "true",
    "returnFaceLandmarks": "false",
    "returnFaceAttributes":
        "age,gender,headPose,smile,emotion," +
        "occlusion,accessories,blur,exposure,noise"
}

// Perform the REST API call.
$.ajax({
    url: uriBase + "?" + $.param(params),

    // Request headers.
    beforeSend: function(xhrObj){
        xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/octet-stream");
        xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", subscriptionKey);
    },

    type: "POST",

    // Request body.
    body:[y],
```

})

I expected it to work but the API gives an error:400 image too small
I have to submit this tomorrow
please help

Answer (score 0):

If that's the error message then it means your image is invalid. According to the official doc:

> JPEG, PNG, GIF (the first frame), and BMP format are supported. The
>   allowed image file size is from 1KB to 6MB. The minimum detectable
>   face size is 36x36 pixels in an image no larger than 1920x1080 pixels.
>
> Images with dimensions higher than 1920x1080 pixels will need a
>   proportionally larger minimum face size. Up to 100 faces can be
>   returned for an image. Faces are ranked by face rectangle size from
>   large to small. For optimal results when querying Face - Identify,
>   Face - Verify, and Face - Find Similar ('returnFaceId' is true),
>   please use faces that are: frontal, clear, and with a minimum size of
>   200x200 pixels (100 pixels between eyes).

Source: https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395236

I recommend you passing a valid existing image prior than trying with the webcam. Once you fix this, test with the image captured by the webcam.